# Beamer and Google Earth (how to call a vi)

Tags: beamer

I did a movie using Google Earth and I would like to call this video via my PDF presentation constructed by the beamer class, so how can I proceed?

I know that it is very easy to call videos like .mp3, .mp4, .avi, etc ..., but I never faced before to call a video in the Google Earth using beamer.

Comment: é: Welcome to tex.sx! Note that it is unusual around here to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to have any greeting.

Comment: é: Your question title is a bit confusing.  Do you mean "how to call a *video*"? Or "how to call `.avi`" maybe?

Answer (score 1):

What file format does your video have? Looking at the [help of google earth](http://earth.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=22379&topic=23666) it seems that at least the pro version allows you to chose from different file formats such as AVI and WMF.

Having either format it should not be a problem to get the movie in the presentation with e.g. the [`movie15`](http://ctan.org/pkg/movie15) package.

Comment: I have .kmz files when I save my movie in Google Earth. But, fortunately, I could display the video using the command \movie[externalviewer]{Cyclone Areas}{cyclone_regions.kmz} without the package movie15. Thanks by the hint. Cheers!

Comment: I have .kmz files when I save my movie in Google Earth. But, fortunately, I could display the video using the command \movie[externalviewer]{Cyclone Areas}{cyclone_regions.kmz} without the package movie15. Thanks by the hint. Cheers!

Comment: kmz files seems to [require a geobrowser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) installed on the computer. So you need to make sure that the computer you give the presentation on also has GoogleEarth or something similar installed.